# Lua pattern to match the path

Tags: string, lua, substring, lua-patterns

I would like to take a string representing a file path, strip off the file name and save just the path.

For example, if I have:

```
"/folder1/folder2/file.name"
```

I would like to end up with `"/folder1/folder2/"` in my string.

I've been playing around with `string.match()` as documented here:  http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial

I have the following code:

```
mystring = "/var/log/test.log"
print(string.match(mystring, "%/"))
```

When I run this script, I end up with just a '/' returned. 
I was expecting that it would return the positions of the two '/' in the string. 
I've also tried replacing the pattern `"%/"` with just `"/"` but that gives me the same results.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple but I can't see what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the pattern `%/` or `/`, you are telling `string.match` to look for a string `/` and that's what you got. Try with this:

```
local mystring = "/var/log/test.log"
print(string.match(mystring, ".+/"))
```

Here the pattern `.+/` means to look for one or more whatever characters(`.`) followed by a `/`. `+` means it's greedy, i.e, match as long as possible.

Comment: No need to escape `/`.

Comment: @lhf Fixed now, sometimes I forgot what are all the magic characters. But escaping `/` works as well and that's one of the reasons I love about Lua.

Comment: fails with escape sequences in the path though.

Answer (score 0):

Try any this options:

```
local mystring = "/var/log/test.log"
print(mystring:gsub('([%w+]+%.%w+)$',''))
```

> output: /var/log/

```
local mystring = "/var/log/test.log"
print(mystring:match('^(/.+/)'))
```

> output: /var/log/

Or too a simple function

```
    function anystring(string)
       local string = string:match('^(/.+/)')
       if anystring then
          return string
       else
          return false
       end
    end

local mystring = anystring('/var/log/test.log')

print(mystring)
```

> output: /var/log/

You can be as specific as possible when putting the pattern to avoid code errors